# VB.NET MutliThreading

Tags: vb.net

I have trying to use Multithreading for Post Method, but i found out that when i Generate some Random Numbers they Double itself, i tought to make it like each Thread does the Same "Generates the Code" expl. 951212 and the other Thread gens a new Code too expl. 251951 Help here is my Code:

```
Imports System.Threading
Public Class Form1
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
    End Sub
    Public Sub Post1()
        Dim gen As New Random
        Dim myrand As Integer
        Do
            myrand = gen.Next(0, 10101010)
            ListBox1.Items.Add(myrand.ToString)
            Label1.Text = ListBox1.Items.Count
        Loop
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Thread1 As New Thread(AddressOf Post1) : Thread1.Start()
        Dim Thread2 As New Thread(AddressOf Post1) : Thread2.Start()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Example of Post Request:

```
Dim postdata as string = "name=" + myrand.ToString + "&email=" + myrand.ToString + "@gmail.com" + "&securitycode="1234"
```

Comment: First things first, **NEVER** set `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` to `False`.  If you feel you need to then it means that you're doing something that you shouldn't so you should determine how to do that the proper way first.  If you need to add items to a `ListBox` - or do anything that affects any control - then you should be delegating to the UI thread to do so.  Learn how to do that now.  [This](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?498387) will help.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you think you're doing there but there's no posting going on.  Is this just a dummy up so you can see how the random numbers work?

Comment: I don't want to Leak my POST Source Code, so i made this Example, because i need to be able to have like 1 Thread has the Name = 51929 and the Others have other Names to i will Code a Auto Register Bot, but the Problem is sometimes it POST's the Same Code so its not that Efficient when i use 500 Threads i want that all Threads can Generate another Number so it will be the Name for the Post Request.

Comment: That's information that you ought to include in your question.  If your point here is just to generate unique names then don't use a `Random` at all.  Use the [`Guid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.guid?view=netframework-4.7.2) data type.  It's [`NewGuid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.guid.newguid?view=netframework-4.7.2) method will generate a new value.  That said, can you not simply use the `ManagedThreadId` of the `Thread` itself?

Comment: Look i edited i think you can Understand now what i mean. I dont want to Send the Same String 500 Times, on Post Request i want that each Thread can make itself a new Number. So all Threads Generate other Numbers.

Comment: I already understood that and I have already addressed it in multiple ways in both comments and an answer.  What do you not understand about the information I've provided?  In future, please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.  Providing a simplified example to illustrate the issue is often a good thing but it's also a good thing to explain that that is what you're doing and how the example differs from your actual code. We shouldn't have top guess things that you already know just because you don't want to type a few more sentences in your question.

Comment: Thanks i think the last EDIT of your Text was the Answer :) TY

Comment: One thing to consider with that solution is whether or not a thread ID might be reused, in which case you would get the same random number again.  I'm not sure whether that's a possibility or not and, even if it is, your app might have to run for quite a long time before the system starts recycling IDs.

Comment: One way to get around that would be to use a seed that combines the current system time and the thread ID.  The time ID would ensure that two instances created at the same time used different seeds and the time would ensure that two instances created on threads with the same ID used different seeds.

Comment: If an answer solves your problem then please indicate that by accepting the answer.  This tells everyone that you no longer need assistance without their having to open the thread and it also helps those with a similar issue to know that there is an existing solution.

Answer (score 0):

That you have encountered this issue means that you haven't bothered to do the reading you should have on generating random numbers.  The documentation for the `Random` class explicitly states what the problem is:

> The random number generation starts from a seed value. If the same
>   seed is used repeatedly, the same series of numbers is generated.

and how to fix it:

> To improve performance, create one Random object to generate many
>   random numbers over time, instead of repeatedly creating new Random
>   objects to generate one random number.

So, the solution to your issue is to create one `Random` object and then use that same object in both threads.

The real solution is to read the documentation first **EVERY** time you have a problem.  You should **NEVER** post a question here (or anywhere else for that matter) without having read the relevant documentation first.  If that doesn't help and neither do relevant web searches or explicit searches of this site, **THEN** you would post a new question.

Given that you're unlikely to read this for yourself, the documentation also says that instance members of the `Random` class are not guaranteed to be thread-safe.  That means that you may need to protect calls to the `Next` method, e.g. using a `SyncLock` statement.  That will ensure that everything associated with generating a new random number is done for one thread before another thread tries to do the same:

```
Private ReadOnly rng As New Random
Private ReadOnly syncRoot As New Object

Private Function GetNextRandomNumber() As Integer
    SyncLock syncRoot
        Return rng.Next(0, 10101010)
    End SyncLock
End Function
```

You could even build thread-safety into your own derived class if you wanted:

```
Public Class ThreadSafeRandom
    Inherits Random

    Private ReadOnly syncRoot As New Object

    Public Overrides Function [Next]() As Integer
        SyncLock syncRoot
            Return MyBase.[Next]()
        End SyncLock
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function [Next](maxValue As Integer) As Integer
        SyncLock syncRoot
            Return MyBase.[Next](maxValue)
        End SyncLock
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function [Next](minValue As Integer, maxValue As Integer) As Integer
        SyncLock syncRoot
            Return MyBase.[Next](minValue, maxValue)
        End SyncLock
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function NextDouble() As Double
        SyncLock syncRoot
            Return MyBase.NextDouble()
        End SyncLock
    End Function

    Public Overrides Sub NextBytes(buffer As Byte())
        SyncLock syncRoot
            MyBase.NextBytes(buffer)
        End SyncLock
    End Sub

End Class
```

You could then use an instance of the `ThreadSafeRandom` class in exactly the same way as you'd usually use a `Random` object and assume that it will be safe to use in multiple threads.

EDIT:

As another option that would mean not having to worry about thread-safety, you could use the ID of the current thread as a seed for the `Random` object.  That ID is guaranteed to be unique so there can't be any issues with multiple instances generating the same sequence of numbers:

```
Dim gen As New Random(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)
```